# how to recognize if month has 30 or 31 days in sqlg

Tags: postgresql, datetime, plpgsql

I need to get last of the five days from month like:

```
1-5 = 5
6-10 = 10
...
26-30/31 = 30/31 (here can be 6 days depending on the month)
```

I've prepared function like

```
create or replace function getfirstdayoffive()
returns date
as
$$
select date_trunc('month', current_date - 5)::date
+ (least(ceil(extract(day from current_date - 5) / 5) * 5,
date_part('day', date_trunc('month', startOp) + interval '1 month - 1 day')))::int - 1;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

and it is working fine to return last day of five. How can I modify it so it would recognize if the last period should have 5 or 6 days?

Answer (score 1):

try following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.days_in_month(d date)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT date_trunc('month', $1::timestamp + interval '1 month')::date 
       - date_trunc('month', $1::timestamp)::date;
$function$
```

Comment: this will only give information about number of days in month, no? to use it inside my ceil block I would have to make some kind of if statement? if result = 30 then, else ...?

Comment: @mario - there are two possibilities - a) use CASE WHEN statement, b) use plpgsql language. SQL language is good for shorter one line function. More complex functions are pretty unreadable - and plpgsql is better then

Comment: I'm trying to use your function like this, but for now I got an error on if statement

create or replace function getfirstdayoffive()
returns date
as
$$
select date_trunc('month', current_date - 5)::date
+ (least(ceil(if(days_in_month(current_date) = 30, extract(day from current_date - 5) / 5) * 5, extract(day from current_date - 6) /6) * 6),
date_part('day', date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month - 1 day'))::int - 1;
$$
language sql
stable;

Comment: @mario - sure, there is not any function `if` in language sql. Please, try to read documentation first - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 1):

Determine the last date of the month, then extract day. If the day is 31 then return minus 6 days, else return minus five days. That assumes you want the last 5 days for Feb. But then except for Feb you could just return the 25th of the month as that is what minus 5 for months with 30 days and minus 6 for days 31 always returns. Note: rather than hard coding current_date this allows a parameter with default value of current_date.

```
create or replace 
function getfirstdayoffive(parm_date_in date default current_date)
returns date
language sql
immutable strict 
as $$
   with last_of_mon(eom) as 
        ( select date_trunc('month',  parm_date_in) + interval '1 month - 1 day' )
   select case when extract(day from eom) = 31
               then (eom-interval '6 days')::date 
               else (eom-interval '5 days')::date 
          end 
     from last_of_mon; 
$$;

select * from  getfirstdayoffive();
select * from  getfirstdayoffive(date '2021-08-15');
select * from  getfirstdayoffive(date '2020-02-15');
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm for now I've got something like :

```
create or replace 
function getlastdayoffive(parm_date_in date default current_date)
returns timestamp
language sql
immutable strict 
as $$
   with last_of_mon(eom) as 
        ( select date_trunc('month',  parm_date_in) + interval '1 month - 1 day' )
   select case when extract(day from eom) = 31
               then (least(ceil(extract(day from parm_date_in - 5) / 5) * 5, date_part('day', date_trunc('month', parm_date_in) + interval '1 month - 1 day')))::timestamp
               else (least(ceil(extract(day from parm_date_in - 6) / 6) * 6, date_part('day', date_trunc('month', parm_date_in) + interval '1 month - 1 day')))::timestamp
          end 
     from last_of_mon; 
$$;
```

But I can't cast to timestamp, how can it be done? if I return integer then I got what I wanted, but the poblem is I need to have a full date in format YYYY-MM-dd

Comment: you should to define result type as `date`. Next, you can write `select (case when ...)::date from last_of_mon`